# Webpack-dev-server "Cannot GET /"

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, webpack

i'm trying to get my webpack-dev-server to run but i face always the error "Cannot Get /" at the browser.
I know that there are serveral questions with the same error, but none of them helped me, so now i will try my luck :)

these are my webpack-config.js configurations:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/app.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  }
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "html-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.6.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.8",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  }
}
```

And the script to find the bundle.js from index.html looks like that:

```
<script type="module" src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

Side note: index.html is not in the dist folder like bundle.js, but i get the same error anyways.

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution. It works great! A few notes I've noticed while breaking my head here as well. It seems you can use this config with `"webpack": "^5.74.0"`, `"webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"`,`"webpack-dev-server": "^4.10.0"`. Also, the `publicPath: '/dist'` must have the prefix `/` because the `devServer.static` says `/`. But this all of course is only relevant for `mode: 'development'`. Did you do something different for `mode: 'production'`? Thanks

Comment: Please move your solution into an answer. You can then accept your own answer if you wait for 2 days.

Comment: webpack-config.js file changes worked for me

Comment: Answers don't belong in the question. I've moved your _solution_ to an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `output.publicPath` to `auto`

https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/#automatic-publicpath

and run dev server via webpack:

https://github.com/evenstensberg/webpack-react-boilerplate/blob/master/package.json#L9

You also need a html file:

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/

Comment: Thanks for ur answer! the message "Cannot GET /" got away, but my project dont't get rendered anymore.. When i'm using lite-server it works fine, but with webpack not.. I'm updating my question for better understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer was originally posted into the question by [phpet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15661641/phpet)

---

If anyone will face the same issue:

"webpack-dev-server" is since 5.0 (or so) no longer supported. You have to change it to

"start": "webpack serve",

Moreover, here my webpack-config.js file changes, which did the trick:

```
    const path = require('path');
     
    module.exports = {
        mode: 'development',
        entry: './src/app.ts',
        output: {
            filename: 'bundle.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            publicPath: '/dist/',
        },
        devServer: {
            static: {
                directory: path.join(__dirname, '/')
            }
        },
       .
       .
       .
};
```